# Testing the Oracle to_date function

Tags: oracle, testing, grails, grails-orm

I'm writing an integration test in Grails using GORM.

I want to do something like the following:

```
delete from Statistic 
where stat_date = TO_DATE(:month_year, 'MON-YYYY')
```

But I get the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected token: TO_DATE in statement [delete
>   from statistics where stat_date=TO_DATE(?, 'MON-YYYY')]

I think the error is caused by the in memory database used by GORM (is it H2?) not supporting the to_date function.

Any ideas on how to write the delete SQL so that it works in a test and in live?

As I only really care about the Month and Year one thought I had would be to delete the records where the stat_date is between the first and last date of the given month.

Can any one think of a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, H2 doesn't support TO_DATE, it's in [1.4.x roadmap](http://www.h2database.com/html/roadmap.html). Instead you can use the [EXTRACT](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#extract) function that exists both in Oracle DB and H2.

Comment: Excellent, this has worked very well, thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 27):

This still comes up as number 1 on google searches so here's what worked for me.

My unit tests/local environment build and populate a schema using sql files. I created the following alias in the sql file

```
-- TO_DATE 
drop ALIAS if exists TO_DATE; 
CREATE ALIAS TO_DATE as '
import java.text.*;
@CODE
java.util.Date toDate(String s, String dateFormat) throws Exception { 
  return new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).parse(s); 
} 
';
```

Notice the use of single quotes instead of $$ in [h2 user defined functions](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions) as that is the only format that worked for me.

Comment: I'm not the author but I would say this is the correct answer. Because the choosen answer suggest to modify the SQL, however, if you use H2 for Unit tests you will not change your code to make your test case work.

Answer (score 8):

I had to adjust bluesman's answer in order to make it work for the date formats that are commonly used in our Oracle sql.

This version supports dateFormats like 'DD-MON-YYYY'

```
-- TO_DATE
drop ALIAS if exists TO_DATE;
CREATE ALIAS TO_DATE as '
import java.text.*;
@CODE
java.util.Date toDate(String s, String dateFormat) throws Exception {
  if (dateFormat.contains("MON")) {
      dateFormat = dateFormat.replace("MON", "MMM");
  }
  if (dateFormat.contains("Y")) {
      dateFormat = dateFormat.replaceAll("Y", "y");
  }
  if (dateFormat.contains("D")) {
      dateFormat = dateFormat.replaceAll("D", "d");
  }
  return new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).parse(s);
}
';
```

I found the tips on this blog post http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/ helpful in figuring out how to translate the Oracle date formats into SimpleDateFormat's formats.

Answer (score 5):

```
java.util.Date toDate(String dateTime, String dateFormat) throws Exception {
    if (dateFormat.contains("MON")) {
        dateFormat = dateFormat.replace("MON", "MMM");
    }
    if (dateFormat.contains("Y")) {
        dateFormat = dateFormat.replaceAll("Y", "y");
    }
    if (dateFormat.contains("D")) {
        dateFormat = dateFormat.replaceAll("D", "d");
    }
    if (dateFormat.contains("HH")) {
        dateFormat = dateFormat.replaceAll("HH", "hh");
    }
    if (dateFormat.contains("hh24")) {
        dateFormat = dateFormat.replaceAll("hh24", "hh");
    }
    if (dateFormat.contains("MI") || dateFormat.contains("mi")) {
        dateFormat = dateFormat.replaceAll("MI", "mi").replaceAll("mi", "mm");
    }
    if (dateFormat.contains("SS")) {
        dateFormat = dateFormat.replaceAll("SS", "ss");
    }
    return new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).parse(dateTime);
}
```

Comment: consider explaining your code, we try to make questions as useful for everyone with a similiar problem as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can define your own TO_DATE like

```
    CREATE ALIAS TO_DATE AS $$
java.util.Date to_date(String value, String format) throws java.text.ParseException {

java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = new  java.text.SimpleDateFormat(format);
    return dateFormat.parse(value);
}
$$;
```

see http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions