# Function "TO_DATE" not found in H2 database

Tags: java, sql, h2, to-date

I have a SQL statement and trying execute with H2 in-memory database in Java. The following exception thrown.

SQL:

```
SELECT ACCT_RULE_ID, ACCT_ACTION_ID 
  FROM ACCT_RULE 
 WHERE (ACCT_ACTION_ID = ?) 
   AND (START_DATETIME <= to_char(?, 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MI:SS AM')) 
   AND (STOP_DATETIME > to_char(?, 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MI:SS AM'))
```

Replacing first parameter with Id and second and third parameter with new Date() value.

```
Exception:
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "TO_DATE" not found; SQL statement:
```

Comment: I'm using java.util.Date()

Answer (score 15):

you should be able to create your own `to_date` function

```
drop ALIAS if exists TO_DATE; 
CREATE ALIAS TO_DATE as '
import java.text.*;
@CODE
java.util.Date toDate(String s, String dateFormat) throws Exception { 
  return new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).parse(s); 
} 
'
```

Of course you could also just use `parsedatetime()` per David Small's answer

Answer (score 5):

One way to remove the time portion from a date-time field in H2, is to format the field as a string and then parse it. This worked for me:

```
PARSEDATETIME(FORMATDATETIME(field_name, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

H2's parse and format date functions follow the [java.text.SimpleDataFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) semantics.

*Yes, it is NOT super optimized. This is fine for our needs since we only use H2 for unit tests.*

Answer (score 2):

H2 database does not have TO_CHAR() function. But H2 database does have sysdate, dual, varchar2 which makes writing oracle query that will run on H2 database quite easy. So you can write a function instead which will H2 database function alias for making it handle date/timestamp with format. `TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')` can be used in H2 database.

Comment: I believe Tijo was suggesting that you use a [User Defined Function](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions),. More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10903425/443633. Which does work. Thanks Tijo!

Answer (score 1):

Despite the lack of documentation there are TO_DATE function in PostgreSQL compatibility mode since 2.0.204.

[Changelog](http://www.h2database.com/html/changelog.html) [ticket](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/pull/3275)

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: Nevermind. In the meantime they fixed it.